# How to replace all : with * or x in an ANOVA table?

Tags: tables, pdf, knitr, rmarkdown, bookdown

I am using `bookdown::pdf_document2`. Some journals require all the interaction terms to be formatted as `Term A * Term B` or `Term A x Term B`, not `Term A : Term B` as default in the R's ANOVA table.

```
library(emmeans)

warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)

joint_tests(warp.lm)


 model term   df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 wool           1  48   3.765 0.0582 
 tension        2  48   8.498 0.0007 
 wool:tension   2  48   4.189 0.0210
```

I'd like to replace `wool:tension` with `wool * tension` or `wool x tension` and knit as a .pdf. I am looking for a reusable solution for many manuscripts so that I don't have to find and replace them all the time. I haven't found an example to imitate. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I do not understand your question, maybe add a complete (minimal) example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: mwe]

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r,echo=F}
library(emmeans)
warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
x <- as.data.frame(joint_tests(warp.lm))
x[[1]] <- as.character(x[[1]])
x[[1]][3] <- paste0(x[[1]][1]," $\\times$ ",x[[1]][2])
knitr::kable(x)
```
````

Comment: Thank you very much. This is helpful for the particular example by specifying the row and column of the entity to be modified, i.e. `x[[1]][3]`. What if I have multiple interaction terms. Is there a way to edit them all at once?

Comment: Not sure  ...make the dataframe and then search and replace every `:`  with `gsub` or something else and then `kable` it?  it sounds less troublesome than to try to change the  `joint_tests` behavior...